# Questions based on exercises from textbooks

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

The question [Is there any difference between this two versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27660132/3920237) was recently closed as "primarily opinion-based". The question draws from Exercise 12.21 of [C++ Primer 5th edition](http://www.informit.com/store/c-plus-plus-primer-9780321714114), which states:

```
We could have written StrBlobPtr’s deref member as
follows:

    std::string& deref() const
    { return (*check(curr, "dereference past end"))[curr]; }

Which version do you think is better and why?
```

At face-value, the exercise is asking about the stylistic differences between two code samples (which is provided earlier in the section). If so, the exercise is a useless one. This seems highly suspect, as one user pointed out,

> Two people chose to close this as "primarily opinion-based". But I
>   doubt that a C++ text book would ask an opinion-based question as an
>   exercise, would it?

There are several problems at play here. The ability for others to answer the question is severely limited because it requires one to:

- have access to the book,
- consume and comprehend a wealth of knowledge (aka, read through potentially several chapters or the whole book leading up to the exercise),
- magically be able to read the author's mind

This puts the burden on the question asker to provide more context in the question so it can be become answerable. This is difficult because the question asker may not know *what* is important to provide, nor understand the relationship between the exercise and the information contained in the preceding chapters. This leads to the perception that the exercise is a useless one.

One user, who does have access to the book, seems to suggest that there isn't anything else to it. I find this hard to believe, but without owning the book, I cannot continue the discussion any further. This is unfortunate because the question as it stands requires remarkable insight to answer, which is easier for someone who owns the book.

The problem is, if the question is closed, nobody can come along and answer it. And it would take major convincing to have someone who does have the book (or for the OP to have a flash of insight) to edit the question for re-opening.

I would like to see the question re-opened sometime in the future, but should the issue just be dropped?

---

<sup>For a question with a similar (but not the same) issue, see [C++11 type deduction vs const char *](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27550539/3920237). The OP asks an article where the author suggests that there is a subtle difference between two pieces of code, when most of the users in the thread agree that there is no difference.</sup>

Comment: I'm not a C++ or byte code person. That being said, it is possible that a lower-level optimization may be present. I would assume that `p` needs to be allocated a block of memory and then deallocated, as opposed to being stored in a register temporarily. If that's the case, then the question is not opinion-based. It would appear as such.

Comment: IMO, the question has no future value to the majority of readers here (who apparently don't have the book) if it's not self-sufficient without that content, and therefore it should be closed. If it can be edited and restated in a manner that does not require access to the book's content in order to explain, it should stay open.

Answer (score 6):

When I glance over that question, I also would flag to close it as "Primarily Opinion Based."

Without discussing the contents in depth, take a look at what the actual question is:

> What is the point of this problem?

That is the last line of the question. It's true that the book probably won't ask an opinion-based question. But the question that **the OP is asking us to answer** is certainly opinion based. I can imagine a trillion different answers to that from a trillion different people.

All of this analysis is before considering other issues with the question. As Ken White mentioned in [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281173/questions-based-on-exercises-from-textbooks#comment134104_281173), the question has very little value to future readers in its current state. That would be another reason it should be closed.

If your main concern is that the question won't be answered, either direct the OP to this thread so he can edit his post, or take a step back and figure out a way to phrase the question that:

- Will be useful to future readers
- Has an *explicit* question statement (not just "what is the point?")
- (As Ken said) doesn't require access to the book

Then you can ask it for yourself.

I can see the value in the question, but not in the way that it is currently stated.

Comment: You seem to think I was the one that asked the question. I wasn't.

Comment: @remyabel ah, you're right. let me fix my answer. Read through it fairly quickly...without coffee...in another country. :)

Comment: No, _"What is the point of this problem?"_ is not asking for an opinion but just asking for an explanation of the solution/answer. There might be 2 or 3 (good) answers to that  but not a trillion. I just voted to reopen.

Comment: The question seems reasonable to me. The textbook shows two functions that appear to be identical, and the OP is asking how the two are different. Is it just a stylistic difference (spacing, named temporary), or is there a semantic difference (maybe a copy can be elided in one case but not the other)? That seems valid to me.